# Why the name IntSupplier and not ToIntSupplier?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I'm a little confused with the naming conventions used in default functional interface names available in javax.util.function package:

For instance, primitive specialization of Function have names like:
IntFunction/LongFunction/DoubleFunction in which **argument type** is of specified type

But primitive specialization of Supplier have names like:
BooleanSupplier/DoubleSupplier/LongSupplier/IntSupplier in which **return type** is of specified type.

If you compare the name and functionality of other interfaces in java.util.function, shouldn't the names have been like:
ToBooleanSupplier/ToDoubleSupplier/ToLongSupplier/ToIntSupplier?

Comment: No, they should not. `ToBooleanSupplier` does not make any sense.

Comment: Perhaps because `To` implies sending and `Supplier` implies receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "to" in `ToIntFunction`, `ToDoubleFunction`, et al indicates that something is being converted *to* something else. The function's input parameters are being converted into an int/double/whatever.

The word "supplier" denotes a function that takes no input and returns some value. It *supplies* values. There's no input, only output.

Adding "to" would be redundant and/or misleading: redundant because the fact that it returns values is already indicated by the word "supplier"; misleading because there's no conversion. The values are generated out of thin air.